# Zend license restrictions with modified code

Tags: php, zend-framework, licensing

If I'm to take parts of Zend Framework and changed them (add something, remove...), and then changed it's name, for example Zend_Config to My_Config or Zend_Application_Bootstrap to My_Application_Bootstrap, and then distribute such a code with a commercial license would I then be violating Zend's licence?

If that is not an option, what can I do then? Do I need to use their code "as is" without changes if I want do distribute it with my commercial application?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would want to do this. If it's for your own application, just extend the classes. If you're fixing a bug, submit it back to Zend. In some other situation, the license is pretty permissive (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641804/how-to-modify-code-with-a-new-bsd-license for a possible dupe)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [license](http://framework.zend.com/license), you are able to modify it as you wish and distribute it freely, as long as the copyright notice is maintained.

As far as a more elegant solution, extend the Zend Framework instead of modifying it. This will allow you to upgrade the framework much more easily. I would have My_Config extend Zend_Config and then change the things that needed to be changed. Same with the bootstrap, etc.

Comment: Extending classes doesn't make sense to me since I don't need all the features provided by original code. Also, my goal is to make code slimmer and optimized.

Comment: I don't want to use full ZFW for my applications, just few components and primarily reason for changing class names is to go with name-spacing (e.g. My\Application\Bootstrap). Extending would just get code more complicated. So if I understod you right, I just need to keep above notice on original files, and add my doc-block informing future users that code is now licensed under commercial licence and that re-distribution isn't allowed?

Comment: I'm definitely not a lawyer, but what you say seems consistent with how I read the license. I think your scenario could really benefit by extending. I understand that it makes the code a little more complicated, but then you can easily separate out what is covered by your license without making it look like you're restricting the license on the Zend Framework stuff.